# quaternion_actionlib

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every body.

I am trying to run a small application using actionlib. I convert in a callback function, degrees to quaternions, as it is shown in the following  piece of code:

```
double th=D2R*(atan2( msg.pose.pose.orientation.y, msg.pose.pose.orientation.y));
geometry_msgs::Quaternion gth = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);
```

Then, I am trying to assign that quaternion as it follows:

```
move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal;
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w =gth;
```

Then I get the error:

```
cannot convert ‘geometry_msgs::Quaternion’ to ‘geometry_msgs::Quaternion_<std::allocator<void> >::_w_type {aka double}’ in assignment
```

Can anybody give me a clue, in advance thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64278/quaternion_actionlib/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your yaw calculation looks wrong. If you already have a pose, the yaw in radians should already be available in `msg.pose.pose.orientation.z`.

The goal assignment is in error because you are trying to assign a quaternion to the `w` component of another quaternion. Maybe you mean this:

```
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation = gth;
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-04**:
Thank you very much for your answer, I realised that yesterday, it is now working :)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-17**:
@acp please accept the answer so others don't spend time trying to help you solve this problem.